# Ajax Pagination append the element instead of updating id

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am working on Cakephp application. What I want here is to create facebook style pagination. Still I have done with Ajax pagination on simple sorting. Now my logic with this I will create button of next. and render element. Cakephp will itself manage pagination. But my  issue is its rendering my view to particular div(ID) that it ask me during 'update'. My style of dom is...

```
<div class="fb_style" id='1'></div>
<div class="fb_style" id='2'></div>
<div class="fb_style" id='3'></div>
<div class="fb_style" id='4'></div>
<div class="fb_style" id='5'></div>
<div class="fb_style" id='6'></div>
<div id='more button'>MORE BUTTON(ACTUALLY PAGINATOR NEXT LINK)</div>
```

I want to render the div next to id=6 or I can say next to .fb_style:last
My pagination sample code...I simple wish to append to particular dom element.

```
$this->Paginator->_ajaxHelperClass = "Ajax";
$this->Paginator->Ajax = $this->Ajax;
$this->Paginator->options(array('update' => 'listID',
    'url' => array('controller' => 'poets', 'action' => 'index', $separator),
    'indicator' => 'loaderID'));
```

If I do it with Jquery means to write function than its quite clumpsy means I have to send total records, than validate the limit manually, on view check if total records are equal or more so I move with above logic let me know if it correct...or any other solution or guide line with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Infinite scrolling JQuery plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/) and it is just working fine. This jquery plugin will give you custom built-in events that you can use to send Ajax request to your controller's method. Also if it will be working then you can change it css to looks like facebook infinite scrolling functionality.

Here is [another post](http://www.netboy.pl/2010/06/infinite-scroll-cakephp/) that will help you how to use it with CakePHP.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. I want to load data and fetch as well when button is clicked I don't wish to fetch all at once and then show in chucks...I wish to trigger query only when button is clicked and then append that data..

Comment: Rahul the above post is same as you are requiring. This Jquery plugin will help you to fetch the data in a blocks not all at once. Thats why you this gives you ajax send event. You might have to customize it like on the button click you need more results. Try to read the documentation of this plugin. It works well.

Comment: I m still bit confused with Implementation. I mean on my view.

$('<div/>').load('Controller/action/page:2/ #content div.post',function(){ 
    $(this).appendTo('#content');
});

N in my controller I use to check if request ajax than render some view. Having loop of next posts.. Means I have to render element. Right..

Comment: Yes you'll have to render your element. You can also use $.ajax() function instead of load() function to send ajax request to the controller's method and render your element in that controller's action.

Answer (score 0):

Use the twitter style of pagination, although your ordering ASC, while facebook and twitter order DESC, it would still apply.

Send the min_id form the first results as param, and use that in your conditions in index() so the next request would get the next block of results.

This is safer then getting page 2 as new records might have been added in the meanwhile so you would be missing records or have duplicates (only applies when you would change to order DESC, for ASC ordering it would be safe to use page 2)

```
'update' => 'listID'
```

should be

```
'update' => '#listID'
```